# Android: empty background over list items in ListView after SetLayoutParams

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

After set layout

```
LayoutParams ll=new LayoutParams(w, h);
ll.leftMargin = l;
ll.topMargin = t;
myListView.setLayoutParams(ll);
```

in Android 4.0.4 position of the ListView is OK:

[image: Android 4.0.4]

But in Android 2.3.6, with the same parms - over ListView items is empty background (this bkg is a part of the list). cant scroll items up:

[image: Android 2.3.6]

How can I set proper position of the ListView in this case?

Comment: can you please post your code ?

Comment: the code is very big; only this visible fragment change ListView layout